# Rails no return value from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, return

I'm trying to read files from in a Model and send the result to a controller. But when I try to display the return value, the only thing I get is the following:

```
#<Modules:0x007fd559e6cf40>
```

In my code, I'm just calling Modules.new() and saving the result in a variable:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    text = Modules.new "../modules"

    puts text
  end
end
```

---

And my Modules-Model reads a directory, looks for a specific file in each subdirectories and returns the content of that file:

```
class Modules
  include Mongoid::Document

  def initialize directory = "./modules"
    modules
  end

  def modules directory = "./modules"

    unless Dir[directory].empty?

      Dir.glob(directory).each do |folder|

        unless Dir["#{directory}/#{folder}"].empty?

          Dir.glob(folder).each do |folder|

            if File.exist? "module.json"
              return open("module.json", "json") do |io| io.read end
            end

          end
        end

       end

    else
      return "Directory empty"
    end

  end
end
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to look for a module.json file in each of these subdirectories?

Because you will need to pass the full path with the directory.  Like:

```
return File.read("#{folder}/module.json") if File.exist? "#{folder}/module.json"
```